# Java how to repeat a statement if it doesn't match a condition

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I am trying to get this program to restart if the user input doesn't match the correct format. However I am unsure of how to do this. I have attached the code below:

```
package weeek4;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class rollNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) { 

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your Roll Number in        this format **-***-*****");

if (input.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{5}")) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you");
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Number");
    }


}
}
```

Comment: use a while loop and a flag?

Comment: Please format your code before posting a question. Also, class names in Java should start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: I would advise you check out the following portion of the Javadoc about `while` statements.: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy . Just use a `loop`(A statement that repeats a block of code until a certain condition is met) and a flag variable(in this case , `k` checks for the condition in the `while` loop)

```
package weeek4;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class rollNumber 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   { 

      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your Roll Number in        this format **-***-*****");
      int k = 0;
      while (k!=1)
      {
         if (input.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{5}")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you");
            k=1;
         }
         else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Number");
      }


    }
}
```

*Hope I helped :)*